# postgres, ubuntu how to restart service on startup? get stuck on clustering after instance reboot

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, postgresql-9.1

I have a `Postgres db 9.1` running on `AWS EC2`, with `ubuntu 12.04`.

I messed a lot with the instance (i.e installed all kinds of postgres X.X before i settled on 9.1).

Now after a month working on that db, I discovered that if I restart my instance `postgres` doesn't load correctly, its status says "Running clusters". this will last forever until I

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

from terminal, and then it works again.

How do I add this line, to ubuntu startup so that each time it loads, it will restart this service, and hopefully solve my problem?

Also any other solution which might solve this.

Comment: If you came here by google (like me) looking for the command to restart postgresql, in my case it was service postgresql-9.3 restart

Comment: I made Albert's comment a Question and Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52610485/how-to-restart-postgresql-in-ubuntu-18-04/52610486

Comment: Came just to get that restart command,
got what I want, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess it would be best to fix the database startup script itself. But as a work around, you can add that line to `/etc/rc.local`, which is executed about last in init phase.

Comment: thanks, but either that rc.local is not running, or the command executed before whatever postgres is doing, or the db overrides it somehow, il look into the logs for info, but off the bat that does not work.

Comment: Maybe there is a race condition, so rc.local gets executed before the regular postgres start process is finished, probably due to the error. Maybe you can add a sleep before the restart and see if that is a valid work around.

Comment: thanks the rc was the right directions, i found the solution in the rcX files. which govern the startup order

Answer (score 45):

On Ubuntu 18.04:

`sudo systemctl restart postgresql.service`

Comment: You need to provide the cluster version as well: sudo systemctl start postgresql-9.5.service

Comment: @Aarvy strangely, on Ubuntu 20 with Postrges 13, the version isn't needed for systemctl

Answer (score 17):

The below command worked for me

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04, via WSL 2 on Windows

Answer (score 10):

## ENABLE is what you are looking for

USAGE:
type this command once and then you are good to go. Your service will start automaticaly at boot up

```
 sudo systemctl enable postgresql
```

DISABLE exists as well ofc

Some DOC: [freedesktop man systemctl](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#Unit%20File%20Commands)

Comment: maybe i think this is for enable....

Comment: @CHAVDAMEET the question was **How do I add this line, to ubuntu startup so that each time it loads, it will restart this service, and hopefully solve my problem?**

Answer (score 6):

## restart postgresql

```
$ sudo service postgresql restart
```

Answer (score 1):

for ubuntu startup so that each time it loads, it will restart this service of Postgres on startup so that you won't have to restart it all the time

```
sudo update-rc.d postgresql enable
```