# How to restart PostgreSQL in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: postgresql

How to restart PostgreSQL via ssh console?

When i search this thing on SO I only find: [postgres, ubuntu how to restart service on startup? get stuck on clustering after instance reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515723/postgres-ubuntu-how-to-restart-service-on-startup-get-stuck-on-clustering-afte)

Comment: Most likely you'll find better results on [dba.se] where this question belongs.

Comment: Thank you Filburt. I've voted to close to move it dba site. I've checked there is no answer to this question in dba site too.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Answer (score 14):

```
systemctl restart postgresql@<postgres_version>-<cluster_name>.service
```

By default cluster_name = 'main', run this command to list all the clusters you have :

```
ls /var/lib/postgresql/
```

if you want to know whether the postgresql is running try this command :

```
systemctl status postgresql@<postgres_version>-<cluster_version>.service
```

Comment: There seems to be two daemons around `postgresql` and `postgresql@XX-main` any idea or reference to what's the difference?

Answer (score 7):

My postgresql service is named postgresql-9.5; in case you get `"postgresql: unrecognized service"` you can find its name with

```
sudo service --status-all | grep postgresql
```

and then proceed as per the accepted answer.

Comment: I got this awk: fatal: cannot open file `/etc/mongod.conf' for reading (No such file or directory)

Comment: @Aarvy, were you running the command as sudo?  There is a reference to mongod.conf in your /etc/init.d/mongod file.  Regardless of this you can also run this command to see the name of your postgres service: `ls -lrt /etc/init.d/postgres*`

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is with your remote configuration**

```
sudo nano /etc/postgresql/13/main/postgresql.conf
```

Uncomment line 59 and change the Listen address to accept connections within your networks.
*

#Listen on all interfaces

> listen_addresses = '*'

#Listen on specified private IP address

> listen_addresses = '192.168.10.11`